# How to use mutate function with loops in R?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am new at R.

I wand to mutate 20 or more variables like below.

```
raw.data <- raw.data %>% 
  mutate(c_time = (c_time_2_1*60 + c_time_2_2) - (c_time_1_1*60 + c_time_1_2),
         m1_time = (m1_time_2_1*60 + m1_time_2_2) - (m1_time_1_1*60 + m1_time_1_2),
         m2_time = (m2_time_2_1*60 + m2_time_2_2) - (m2_time_1_1*60 + m2_time_1_2), 
         q_time = (q_time_2_1*60 + q_time_2_2) - (q_time_1_1*60 + q_time_1_2), 
         ...
         )
```

How can I use loop (whatever it is for-loop or map or else) list below in mutate function.

```
keys = c('c', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', ... , 'm20', 'q', 'qpi', 'qsp', 'qpss', ... )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try some non-standard evaluation :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

bind_cols(raw.data, purrr::map_dfc(keys, ~transmute(raw.data, 
!!.x := !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_2_1')) *60 + !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_2_2')) - 
        !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_1_1'))*60 + !!sym(paste0(.x, "_time_1_2")))))
```

Comment: 'code'
times = c('c', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11',
          'm12', 'm13', 'm14', 'm15', 'm16', 'm17', 'q', 'qpi', 'qsp', 'qpss', 'qsc')
'code'

Comment: @JunghunYoo Sorry, I didn't get you. Did the answer work? did it return error?

Comment: 'code'
bind_cols(raw.data, purrr::map_dfc(times, ~transmute(raw.data,
  !!.x := !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_2_1'))*60 + !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_2_2')) - 
          !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_1_1'))*60 - !!sym(paste0(.x, "_time_1_2")))))
`code`

Comment: When I try to comment on your answer, it did work to add line.

Comment: I tried to follow your answer, and make a code like above. However, the error appears as follows: "The binary operator is an string, not a int."

Comment: @JunghunYoo Can you create a small reproducible example so that I can test this? You can read about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: `sampledata <- data.frame(
  c_time_1_1 = c(8, 12, 15, 18),
  c_time_1_2 = c(30, 0, 10, 40),
  c_time_2_1 = c(9, 12, 15, 18),
  c_time_2_2 = c(0, 15, 30, 45),
  m1_time_1_1 = c(9, 12, 15, 19),
  m1_time_1_2 = c(2, 17, 40, 2),
  m1_time_2_1 = c(9, 12, 15, 19),
  m1_time_2_2 = c(8, 20, 45, 7)
  )

sampledata <- sampledata %>% 
  mutate(c_time = (c_time_2_1*60 + c_time_2_2) - (c_time_1_1*60 + c_time_1_2),
         m1_time = (m1_time_2_1*60 + m1_time_2_2) - (m1_time_1_1*60 + m1_time_1_2),
  )`

Comment: I create a sampledata: 'c_time_1_1' (hour) and 'c_time_1_2' (minute) are the start time of measurement for device 'c', and 'c_time_2_1' (hour) and 'c_time_2_2' (minute) are the end time of measurement. I want to use these variables to find the time it takes to measure device C, but there are so many devices that I want to use loops.

Comment: @JunghunYoo For the sample data shared. If you do `keys <- c('c', 'm1')` and use the above code `bind_cols(sampledata, purrr::map_dfc(keys, ~transmute(sampledata, 
                                                    !!.x := !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_2_1')) *60 + !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_2_2')) - 
                                                      !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_1_1'))*60 + !!sym(paste0(.x, "_time_1_2")))))` you do get the expected output right?

Comment: Oh, now it's working. I didn't do the basics of converting the class 'character' into a 'numeric'. But if I just do "bind_cols", I can't save it. Sample data set shows it at the end of the data matrix, but I can't see it because there are 650 variables in the actual dataset. Is there any way to save only the newly created variables?

Comment: @JunghunYoo Remove `bind_cols` at the beginning. Use `output <- purrr::map_dfc(keys, ~transmute(raw.data, 
!!.x := !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_2_1')) *60 + !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_2_2')) - 
        !!sym(paste0(.x, '_time_1_1'))*60 + !!sym(paste0(.x, "_time_1_2")))))`

Comment: When I tried to save new variables in Raw.data, it was stored with 1,323 variables, whether there was a crash. When I checked the data structure, 650 variables were saved twice and 23 additional newly created variables were saved.